# limit itextsharp pdf to just 1 page

Tags: c#, itext

The contents in my pdf are populated from the database. Is there a way to limit the pdf output to just 1 page even if the content gets longer. Its fine if the pdf would have to cut the extra contents but i just want to limit the pdf to a one page pdf.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of would be to build your PDF normally, save it, then open it again with a PdfStamper and delete everything but the first page.

That sounds like a great way to experience some serious data loss though.

Comment: The content on the pdf is generated on the fly everytime..towards the end of the document, there are going to be testimonials that will come from the db. If there are lots of testimonials that goes to next page, i am told to limit the output to just one page. I will try your idea and see what i get. Thanks Mark.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader();
reader.SelectPages(new int[] { 1 });
```